# Elegant way to prove congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm stuck with the last question of this exercise

**1) First question** asks to solve the linear diophantine

$$143x-840y=1$$

based on the remark $143\times 47 - 840 \times 8 = 1$ *(done)*

**2) second question** asks to prove that if a natural $n$ is coprime with $899$, then

$$n^{840} \equiv 1 \mod 899 $$ (*done* using  Fermat's little theorem on $31$ and $29$ knowing that $899 = 31 \times 29$)

**3) This last question** asks to determine an integer between $100$ and $1000$ such that

$$n^{143} \equiv 2 \mod 899$$

I proved the problem reduces to determining the remainder of $2^{47}$ when divided by $899$ wolframalpha says it's $345$ but I still can't see any elegant way to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: Elegant way to prove *what*, that $\, 2^{\large 47}\equiv 345\pmod{899}?\ $

Comment: yes (based maybe on previous questions if they're of some use)

Comment: It should be easy by CRT, i.e. compute $2^{\large 47}$ mod $29$ & $31$ then lift to their product by CRT.

Comment: Note:  $2^5\equiv1\pmod{31}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy mental arithmetic to compute $2^{\large 47}$ mod $31$ & $29$ then lift it to $31\cdot 29$ by CRT.

$\!\!\bmod \color{#c00}{31}\!:\ \ \,2^{\large 5}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,2^{\large 47}\equiv 2^{\large 2}\equiv\color{#c00} 4$

$\!\!\bmod 29\!:\,\ 2^{\large 28}\!\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,2^{\large 47}\equiv 2^{\large -9}\equiv 1/(-10)\equiv 30/(-10)\equiv -3$

thus $\ {-}3\equiv 2^{\large 47}\equiv \color{#c00}{4\!+\!31}k\equiv 4\!+\!2k\iff 2k\equiv -7\equiv 22\iff\color{#0a0}{k\equiv 11\pmod{\!29}}$

Therefore:  $\,2^{\large 47} = 4+31\color{#0a0}k = 4+31(\color{#0a0}{11\!+\!29}n) = 345 + 31(29n)$

Comment: or $4\equiv2^{47}\equiv26+29k\iff-22\equiv-2k\iff k\equiv11\pmod{31}\\$  and therefore: $2^{47}=26+29k=26+29(11+31n)$

Answer (score 5):

> **Problem**: We want to find the $x$ in range $0 \leq x \leq 898$ such that $2^{47} \equiv x \pmod{899}$.

Here's a relatively fast method for general problems like these called [*square-and-multiply*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring):

We can write $47 = 2^5 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0. \ $  Therefore, $2^{47} = 2^{2^5} \cdot 2^{2^3} \cdot  2^{2^2} \cdot 2^{2} \cdot 2. \ $  And now we can compute these values $\big\{2^{2^k} \big\}_{k=0}^5$ via iterative squaring (and reducing modulo $899$ when necessary):

$\qquad \bullet \ \quad 2^2 \ = \ 4$

$\qquad \bullet \ \quad 2^{2^2} = \ 4^2 = \ 16$

$\qquad \bullet \ \quad 2^{2^3} \ = \ (16)^2 \ = \ 256$

$\qquad \bullet \ \quad 2^{2^4} \ = \ 256^2 \ = \ 65536 \ \equiv \ 808 \pmod{899}$

$\qquad \bullet \ \quad 2^{2^5} \ = \ 808^2 \ = \ 652864 \ \equiv \ 190 \pmod{899}$

Multiply the appropriate values together, reduce modulo $899$, and you're done(!!).  Clearly, this is not the most computationally efficient approach in this specific case—see **Bill Dubuque**'s answer (+1).  But marvel at just how few computations there are relative to the naïve approach!

In general, if the exponent consists of $n$ bits when written in base-$2$, then—if I'm not mistaken—one needs to perform a *maximum* of $2n-3$ multiplications when using square-and-multiply (plus modulo reductions, if desired).  Thus, the number of multiplications required grows logarithmically with the size of the exponent, whereas the number of multiplications required for naïve exponentiation grows *linearly*.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, evaluate $2^{47}$ mod $29$ and $31$. For $31$ we quickly get $4$ mod $31$.

For mod $29$, note that $2^5\equiv3$ so $2^{15}\equiv(-2)$ and $2^{45}\equiv(-8)$ so finally $2^{47}\equiv(-3)$.

From here we do a quick CRT to finish off the problem (assuming you know how to do it; the gist is essentially the Euclidean Algorithm, modified slightly).